# How and where to build UI design in a flutter project?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I am new to flutter. I want to know that when we want to start a flutter project how and where we should build our UI design, in order to not implement a repeated design for every single element(like buttons, title or texts) in the UI and to avoid code duplication in our project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new package in your "lib" folder and name it "widgets", then write your widgets there. Write your widgets as a class. After that you can use your widgets where you want anytime. This is the easiest way.